# How can I just import a subdir and use "subdir.pythonfile.function" in python?

Tags: python, import, subdirectory

I have a python project with following structure:
project
--subdir
----__init__.py
----func.py  (has a function a)
--main.py

I want to use the function "a" in main.py. So I can
`import subdir.func as F`
`F.a()`

But this is not what I want to do, I want to use
`import subdir`
`subdir.func.a()`

How can I do that easily?

---

Solved, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your directory structure as it is and add this line in your **init**.py :

```
from . import func
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me discuss here your current scenario first.
If you print files of 'subdir' here:

```
    import subdir as SD
    print(SD.__file__)
```

It should show the **init**.pyc file name with absolute path.
So to resolve issue you have to import the func.py file in **init**.py file

```
    from . import func
```